# How to get file in the order that the user moved them?

Tags: windows-xp, file-management

I have a user that "sorted" a network folder full of photo by dragging each photo and dropping it before another photo. He did not rename the file at all. On his Windows XP, the Windows Explorer shows the file in the order he dragged them, but on any other computer, the file just appear normally in alphabetical order.

Since he spent multiple hours "sorting" them, is there is any possible way to get that specific file order from his computer?

I tried listing them with the command prompt, but the order is not his.

Is it possible, or should he just start over, by renaming the files 1 to X instead of dragging them?

For example, in Windows XP, when you drag a folder, you get a drop bar that appear indicating where the file will be drop. As long as you do not sort the folder, this is the order in which Windows Explorer will display the files and folder for that user.

[image: Windows XP drag a folder before another]

Comment: Were the modified dates on the files changed when he 'dragged' them into the new location?  If so, then you should be able to sort by modification date to see them in the order he dragged them.

Answer (score 1):

Without renaming the user just arranged them, instead of actually sorting them. There's no way to get the specific files in the order the user arranged them. The user should rename them.

Comment: But his Windows Explorer is displaying the file in the order he placed them, so this information must be available somewhere

Comment: Explorer saves that as part of window information, you probably have to trawl through the registry to find out more.